Can a JS object Property Made Observable
I saw the documentation for makeObservable() method regarding the "annotations" used as the 2nd parameter in the method, in "Available annotations" part it says:
Annotation         Description
observable
observable.deep    Defines a trackable field that stores state. If possible, any value 
                   assigned to observable is automatically converted to (deep) 
                   observable, autoAction or flow based on it's type. 

after that it also says:
Only plain object, array, Map, Set, function, generator function are convertible. Class instances and others are untouched.

I wonder if I have a primitive type property in an object named as obj1 defined as:


{
  value: 12
}



and have


obj2 = makeObservable(obj1, { value: observable })



, does the last statement mean obj2's "value" is not observable since it is neither "Plain object" nor "array or Map" ? But actually I have this example from mobx PlayGround, the "value" field of the

counter

object looks "observable" from the running result, can someone help clarify this ?
